# AutoMapper doesn't throw any exceptions using AssertConfigurationIsValid()

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have a problem when using the method `AssertConfigurationIsValid()`. The expected result should display a exception containing the details of mapping, instead it throws this error:
[image]

I expect to see a well detailed error at this point but instead throw this.

Did I missed something when install `AutoMapper` extension?

Comment: this seems more of an issue with your debugger settings.. Is the exception visible in the output window?

Comment: @sommmen is right. Look at `exception.ToString()`.

Comment: Do you see stack trace and line number of exception? sorry about my poor english

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a matter of getting the wrong result, you're looking the wrong place.

You're showing us a notification that an unhandled exception occurred. It only mentions that "an exception of type X" occurred, it doesn't show you the content of that exception, which is where you want to be looking.

Either change your IDE debug settings to not raise this notification (I generally don't like it), or *handle* your exception (i.e. catch it) and inspect it at debug time.

Note also that `AssertConfigurationIsValid` should generally be used in a test suite, where all exceptions (inside tests) are automatically handled and reported as a test result.